# Enable default camera in Lenovo T410

Tags: video, webcam

I was using Lenovo T410 with Windows. Last week I wiped off Windows and installed Ubuntu 10.10 as my primary OS. Now, I am not sure how to install/enable the default camera in ubuntu. I searched lenovo site for ubuntu drivers but they are all for Windows only.

Comment: please provide the follow information execute in terminal `lsusb` and `lspci` and update your post with this information and will see what happen.

Answer (score 2):

I own a T410 and I have no troubles with the camera. It works out-of-the box, withoug any effort from my side. 
It works both with cheese and skype.
Try <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> as it seems to control the camera somehow (I don't have the user's manual here with me, to check what they actually do).

Comment: According to the hardware manuals, the T410 and T510 use the same camera and it should work out of the box. Thanks for confirming this! Awarding the bounty to this answer (due to the lack of further activity of the questioner).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of webcam programs to access your web cam Cheese is just one.

To test if the default open source drivers are working I access my built in web cam on my laptop using Video for Linux or Video for Linux 2 and vlc media player.

I open vlc media player.
Click on the the Media menu
Either Advanced Open File or Open Capture Device
Choose Capture mode I use Video for Linux 2 [try experimenting with the other modes]

You may need to install Video for Linux in order for the Capture Device to become available.

You can also check if there is a v4l device in the /dev directory.
$ ls /dev/v4l
by-id  by-path
$ ls /dev/v4l/by-*
by-id:
usb-Bison_Electronics_Inc.*BisonCam*_NB_Pro-video-index0

by-path:
pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-video-index0

Answer (score 0):

If the camera is enabled in the BIOS, then it should just work (you can test it by installing and running the webcam program `cheese`).

Comment: From Cheese, I see grey image and nothing else. Let me check from BIOS.

Comment: Nothing from bios too. Not sure how to enable this...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you then (I got a T510 and I was hoping it just works for you the way it does for me).